# Unit test not been started after migrating framework to xcframework

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xctest

We are creating a framework. I am facing an issue that the unit test is not been started. Previously it was working. I tried to add an xcframework to our framework. The build and integration tests all succeed. Only the unit tests never begin. I have created a sample project and try to implement this and there it's working fine.

[image: Error has shown in the pic]